# Starting phantomjs node on Selenium grid on a external machine

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, selenium-grid

I am trying to start a phantomjs node on a virtual machine to connect to my own computer which hosts the hub. I have gotten a generic node set up externally (5 instances of firefox, chrome and one instance of IE). When I try and set up a phantomjs node however, it registers fine from the command prompt, but when I go to the grid console, the following message is displayed:

DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to failed: [myIp] Connection refused: connect

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What commands are you sending to create the node and link to your hub?

Comment: This may be port forwarding issue. Check the port is open on both machine for inbound.

Comment: I am using the following command to create the node and link to my hub:
`phantomjs --webdriver 5558 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://hubIP:5786 --ignore-ssl-errors=true`

Comment: @diieu Both ports are open, would that be causing a possible port forward issue? I am still running into issues with this.

Comment: @Jay so if you go to your http://hubIP:5786 you see the Hub console? Is there anything printed out to the terminal when trying to create the phantomjs node? The command you posted to create a node looks right. What are you sending to create the hub?

Comment: @diieu In my comment above, that is what I am sending to create the hub. Yes it shows the node on the console, but it gives the error message that I provided in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Connection refused when phantomjs is run on different machine than selenium hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306348/connection-refused-when-phantomjs-is-run-on-different-machine-than-selenium-hub)

Referenced this question... Basically had to add the IP of my node machine to the --webdriver param in the command line...